# Java get appointment from exchange with kerberos

Tags: java, kerberos, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to connect with EWS from microsoft to our Exchange. There I get en error. In the trace is:

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

We already have an C# Project which can connect with the Independent webdav library and there it works with the same username and password. So I think it is the problem with the kind of authentication. Is there a open source java library that connect with kerberos? Or may I'm on the wrong way to kill this error.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue your WebDAV requests manually with Apache HttpClient. It supports SPNEGO authentication.

Comment: Do you also have a small sample?

Comment: Does this suffice http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#spnego?